# java post form and get response headers following redirects

Tags: java, php, http, redirect

I am trying to submit a POST request to  login form "http://localhost/cilogin/login/" and get response headers from the JAVA url connection. The login form itself gets a redirect after login to "http://localhost/cilogin/login/success".

I am trying to detect an HTTP 302 redirect through JAVA. But I only get HTTP 200 OK in the response headers I fetched. It's as if JAVA ignores the redirect.
Please help. Code is given below:

```
private boolean doLogin(String pass) throws IOException
        {

            String url ="http://localhost/cilogin/login/"; 

            URL obj = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
            con.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);  //you still need to handle redirect manully.
            HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(true);
            con.setDoOutput(true);
            con.setRequestMethod("POST");
            con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");
            con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");

            con.connect(); 
            String charset = "UTF-8";  // Or in Java 7 and later, use the constant: java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name()
            String param1 = "pd";
            String param2 = pass;
// ...

            String query = String.format("log=%s&pwd=%s&Sub=login", 
        URLEncoder.encode(param1, charset), 
        URLEncoder.encode(param2, charset));


            OutputStream output = con.getOutputStream();
            output.write(query.getBytes(charset));

            int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();

            System.out.println("PASS= "+pass+" code = "+responseCode);

             Map<String, List<String>> map = con.getHeaderFields();

            for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : map.entrySet())     {

                String key = entry.getKey();
                String val = entry.getValue().get(0);
                if(responseCode == 302 && key.equals("Location") && val.equals("http://localhost/cilogin/login/success"))
                {
                    con.disconnect();
                    return true;
                }
            }

            con.disconnect();
            return false;
        }
```

java Response is:

```
PASS= abc code = 200
```

Here "abc" is the String passed to the method doLogin from outside

Comment: It's also possible that your http client library is processing the redirect so you are just seeing the 200 on the final request after the redirect.

Comment: I agree. For instance Apache's HttpClient library also automatically handles GET redirects. Are there any redirect strategies that you can configure for your HttpClient lib?

Comment: There is option in HttpClient library of Apache http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.2.x/tutorial/html/httpagent.html#d5e1169 to get status code is redirect

Comment: @fishi, your suggestion led me to  replace the  HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
            con.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true); with con.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false); and it worked like a charm. am going to answer my own question

Answer (score 1):

The correct code is:

```
 private boolean doLogin(String pass) throws IOException
         {

            String url ="http://localhost/cilogin/login/"; 

            URL obj = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
            //HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(true);
            con.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);  //essential for capturing 302 redirect on successful login

            con.setDoOutput(true);
            con.setRequestMethod("POST");
            con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");
            con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");

            con.connect(); 
            String charset = "UTF-8";  // Or in Java 7 and later, use the constant: java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name()
            String param1 = "pd";
            String param2 = pass;
// ...

            String query = String.format("log=%s&pwd=%s&Sub=Login", 
            URLEncoder.encode(param1, charset), 
            URLEncoder.encode(param2, charset));


            OutputStream output = con.getOutputStream();
            output.write(query.getBytes(charset));

            int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();

            System.out.println("PASS= "+pass+" code = "+responseCode);

            Map<String, List<String>> map = con.getHeaderFields();

            for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : map.entrySet())     {

                String key = entry.getKey();
                String val = entry.getValue().get(0);
                //System.out.printf("%s: %s\n", key, val);
                if(responseCode == 302 && key!=null && key.equals("Location") && val.equals("http://localhost/cilogin/login/success"))
                {
                    con.disconnect();
                    return true;
                }
            }

            con.disconnect();
            return false;
        }
```